# I have to find the nth number that contains the digit k or is divisible by k. (2 <= k <= 9)

Tags: algorithm, math, sequence

Example – if n = 15 & k = 3 Answer : 33 (3, 6, 9, 12, 13, 15, 18, 21, 23, 24, 27, 30, 31, 32, 33)

I started following the sequence but couldn't formulate it

for multiples of 3 -> 3+3+3+4+3+3+4+3+3+4

for containing digit 3 ->

{

range in diff = 100 -> 1+1+1+10+1+1+1+1+1+1 = f(n) say;

range in diff = 1000 -> 
f(n)+f(n)+f(n)+10*f(n)+f(n)+f(n)+f(n)+f(n)+f(n)+f(n) = ff(n) say

range in diff = 10000 ->
ff(n) + ff(n) + ff(n) + 10*ff(n)+ff(n) + ff(n) + ff(n)+ff(n) + ff(n) + ff(n)

same goes further.

}

I have to answer in better than O(n) or in O(1) if possible, Please don't suggest methods like to check every number in a for loop. Thanks.

Edit-I have searched everywhere but couldn't find it answered anywhere so , It's not a duplicate.

Comment: I can imagine O(logn) but for O(1) you basically need to find a formula f(n,k) = solution or not?

Comment: suggest me O(logn)..
Thanks.

Comment: @maraca definitely very interested in solution to this beyond naïve looping

Comment: The number of digits has to be about log_10(n) regardless of anything, since at least 1 in 10 numbers has k as a digit, but with less than log_10(n)-1 digits you don't have n numbers at all. In fact, it is either ceil(log_10(n)) or ceil(log_10(n))+1 . Now go read Gilad's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to think about it that could point you along at least one direction (or, alternatively, a wild-goose chase). Separate the two questions and remove overlapping results:

(1) How many `j-digit` numbers are divisible by `k` ? `[j 9's / k] - [(j-1) 9's / k]`

(2) How many `j-digit` numbers include the digit `k`? `9 * 10^(k-1) - 8 x 9^(k-1)`

Now we need to subtract the `j-digit` numbers that are *both* divisible by `k` and include the digit `k`. But how many are there?

Use divisibility rules to consider the different cases. For example:

```
k = 2
If k is the rightmost digit, any combination of the previous j-1 digits would work.
Otherwise, only combinations with 0,4,6 or 8 as the rightmost digit would work.

k = 5
If k is the rightmost digit, any combination of the previous j-1 digits would work.
Otherwise, only combinations with 0 or 5 as the rightmost digit would work.

etc.
```

(Addendum: I asked the combinatoric question on math.stackexchange and got some interesting [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885253/how-many-k-digit-numbers-are-both-divisible-by-3-and-include-the-digit-3/1885287#1885287). And here's a link to the OP's question on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884303/the-n-th-number-that-contains-the-digit-k-or-is-divisible-by-k-2-le-k-l )

Comment: This answer looks good.  To work out the overlapping results it may help to use dynamic programming based on something like DP[x][y] = number of x digit numbers containing the special digit with value equal to y modulo the special digit, and perhaps DP2[x][y] = number of x digit numbers *not* containing the special digit with value equal to y mod special digit.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz thank you for your comment. I would have to think about the DB definitions you suggested to see if I understand.

Comment: Can you guys provide a working implementation ? I don't see a way to get the nth number easily. Thanks.

Comment: @rishavbansal One way might be: once you determine the number of digits the `nth` number has, fix the leftmost digit and work your way to the right - as in, how many of the special numbers are accounted for, using combinatorics and divisibility rules, if the leftmost digit is `1`? if it's `2`? etc. When you find the appropriate leftmost digit, go to the next one on its right, and so on.

Comment: @rishavbansal see here also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885253/how-many-k-digit-numbers-are-both-divisible-by-3-and-include-the-digit-3/1885287#1885287

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz please see link to the OPs question on math.stackexchange at the end of my answer - it looks like the suggestions there are similar to yours.

Comment: Damn math.stackexchange! I was almost there :-)

Comment: @m69 you can still work out the combinatorics for k=7. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I was taking a less mathematical, more algorithmic approach.

Answer (score -1):

Following up on [גלעד ברקן's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38807931/15472), if you have an O(1) way of calculating `d(j, k)` = numbers with at least one digit k up to j, *discarding numbers that are divisible by k*, then you can calculate `e(j, k)` = numbers with at least on digit k or divisible by k under j as `j/k + d(j, k)`.

This allows you to find `f(n, k)` with binary search, since `k <= f(n, k) <= k*n` and `e(j, k) = n <=> f(n, k) = j`: you essentially try to guess which `j` will yield the expected `n`, in O(log n) tries.

I agree with גלעד ברקן's observation regarding divisibility rules for calculating `d(j, k)` efficiently; but they are not trivial to implement, except for `k=5` and `k=2`.

I strongly doubt that you can improve on O(log n) for this problem; and it may not even be reachable for some values of `k`.

Comment: why isn't the combinatoric/divisibility option for 3 and 9 not trivial as well? I'm lost on how to do it with 7, though :)

Comment: So, how many numbers with the digit 6 are divisible by 3 and under, say, 5000? One thing is there being a divisibility rule (there is one for 7, too), and another using that rule to arrive at d(j, k) without looping j times.

Comment: here you go: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885253/how-many-k-digit-numbers-are-both-divisible-by-3-and-include-the-digit-3/1885287#1885287

Answer (score -1):

This is more complex than I thought, but I think I figured out a solution for the simplest case (k = 2).

First I tried to simplify by asking the following question: Which position in the sequence have the numbers `10^i * k` where `i = 1, 2, 3, ...`? For k = 2 the numbers are 20, 200, 2000, ...

```
i k                                                                  n
1 2    20/2                                                        = 10
2 2   200/2 + 2*  5                                                = 110
3 2  2000/2 + 2* 50        + 18* 5                                 = 1190
4 2 20000/2 + 2*500        + 18*50         + 162*5                 = 12710
i 2    10^i + 2*10^(i-1)/2 + 18*10^(i-2)/2 + 162*10^(i-3)/2 + ?*10^(i-4)/2 + ...
```

In the last line I tried to express the pattern. The first part is the number dividable by 2. Then there are i-1 additional parts for the odd numbers with a 2 at first position, second and so on. The difficult part is to calculate the factors (2, 18, 162, ...).

Here a function returning the new factor for any i:

```
f(i) = 2 * 10^(i-2) - sum(10^(i-x-1)*f(x), x from 2 to i-1) = 2 * 9^(i-2) [thx @m69]
f(2) = 2
f(3) = 2*10 - (1*2) = 18
f(4) = 2*100 - (10*2 + 1*18) = 162
f(5) = 2*1000 - (100*2 + 10*18 + 1*162) = 1458
```

So using this information we can come up with the following algorithm:

Find the highest number `10^i*2` which does not exceed the position. (If `n` is in the range `[positionOf(10^i*2), positionOf(10^i*2) + (10^i)]` then we already know the solution: `10^i*2 + (n - positionOf(10^i*2))`. E.g. if we find that i=2 we know that the next 100 values are all in the sequence: [201, 300], so if 110 <= n <= 210, then the solution is 200+(n-110) = n+90.)

```
int nn = positionOf(10^i * 2);
int s = 10^i * 2;
for (int ii = i; ii >= 0; ii--) {
  for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    if (j == 1 || j == 6) {
      if (n <= nn + 10^ii)
        return s + nn - n;
      nn += 10^ii;
      s += 10^ii;
      int tmp = positionOf(10^ii);
      if (nn +  tmp > n)
        break;
      nn += tmp;
      s += 10^ii;
    } else {
      int tmp = positionOf(10^ii * 2);
      if (nn + tmp > n)
        break;
      nn += tmp;
      s += 10^ii * 2;
    }
  }
}
return s;
```

This is only untested uncomplete pseudo-code (I know that you can't use `^` in Java), ii = 1 or 0 needs to be treated as special case, this missing and how to find `i` isn't shown either or the answer would become too long.

Comment: 2, 18, 162, 1458... = 2 * (9^0, 9^1, 9^2, 9^3...)

Comment: Good observation +1.  For the moment I leave the answer as is, because it shows how I came up with those numbers and maybe it can be generalized to any k somehow.

Comment: I have deduced a solution from the answers on my question on this link
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884303/the-n-th-number-that-contains-the-digit-k-or-is-divisible-by-k-2-le-k-l

which seems to be working fine.

Answer (score -1):

this can be solved using binary search+ digit dp.....
with time complexity of o(logn*)
for solution seecode:`enter code here`https://ideone.com/poxhzd